# Fallback NGINX location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I’m new to NGINX and I am migrating a server. I haven’t finished everything on the new server, so I want it to match to the new server, unless that resource or path doesn’t exist. If so, I want to send it to the old server. Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 17):

I did this by a hack with `proxy_next_upstream`

Define a upstream, forward most of reqeusts to new_server by controlling the weight, `proxy_next_upstream` will retry to forward the failed request to next server (old_server)

```
upstream backend {
    server new_server weight=10000;
    server old_server weight=1;
}

server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_404 http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 non_idempotent;
    }
}
```

===========

Solution II

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://new_server;
        error_page 404 500 502 503 504 = @fallback;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://old_server;
    }
}
```